# Can I get the Azure Function auth code via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I have an azure http-triggered function deployed via terraform. I need to call this function from two places:

1. Another function
2. The function itself (kind of recurrency)

The problem I met is that using terraform I can get `default_function_key` by:

```yaml
data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "my_function_auth_keys" {
  name                = azurerm_function_app.replication_prolong_water_meters.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_function_app.my_function.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [azurerm_function_app.my_function]
}
```

It fits the #1 case (I can append `?code${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.my_function_auth_keys.default_function_key}` to the function URL)

But when I want to inject the same URL configuration to `my_function` function and try to apply terraform, it gives me the `Error: cycle` exception.

So how I can get a valid URL with the authentication code for this function?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code .

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "fnexample" {
  name                     = "funcptestsa"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azurefunctions-test-plan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "tstazure-functions"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.fnexample.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.fnexample.primary_access_key
}

data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "example" {
  name                = "tstazure-functions"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

 depends_on = [ 
    azurerm_function_app.example
  ]
}


output "hostname" {
  value = azurerm_function_app.example.default_hostname
}

output "functionkeys" {
  value = data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.example.default_function_key
  sensitive = true
}

Get the url in output value.

output "my_function_url_with_auth" {
  value ="${azurerm_function_app.example.default_hostname}/api/my_function?code=${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.example.default_function_key}"

  sensitive = true
}
```

Use  the Output value to refer in function.
If the Url is generated using the function , then there will be circular cycle issue.

Try to create url separately in locals to inject.

```
locals {
  new_http_url=  "${azurerm_function_app.example.default_hostname}/api/my_function?code=${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.example.default_function_key}"
}
```

[image]

Reference [function_app_function | Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app_function)